# Storing the output of a partial to a local var, then send as json to ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a ajax call, and I want to return a json response.

The controller will need to get the output of a partial, plus add some other properties to the object then serialize to json.

How can I get the output of a partial and store it to this object?

I want something like:

```
def my_action

   my_output.html = render :partial => 'test', ....
   my_output.some_prop1 = 234234

   my_output.to_json
end
```

Then in my view I will inject the html into the DOM, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `render_to_string` in place of `render`.

```
def my_action
   output = {}
   output[:html] = render_to_string :partial => 'test', ....
   output[:some_prop1] = 234234
   render :json => output
end
```

Comment: Do I need to make my_output a specific type first?  or just my_output = "" is enough of a declaration?

Comment: btw, it says it can't find the template. it worked when I was doing it w/o render_to_string

Comment: my code:  render_to_string :partial => 'test', :locals => { :obj1 => obj1 }, :layout => false

Comment: It may depend on your version of Rails, but I don't think you need the `to_json` if you're passing it to `:json =>`

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't find it. Perhaps you should pass `:partial => 'controller/partial'`?

Comment: I tried controller/partial (posts/test), error is: <h1>Template is missing</h1>
<p>Missing partial posts/test with...